# grep and if function ( x[4] == "A" & x[6] == "1000" & x[4] == "B" & x[6] == "1000")

Tags: r

I need help on this, please. Have been struggle for couple hours again.......

```
# open file for data connection
data <- file("data.log", open = "r")

# do readlines for the first
# there should be more than  500 lines for thousands of observations
rl <- readLines(data)
```

the labels/headers that are not included in the data: time , group, task, complete or not, hours, credit

```
[1]  10:00 A task1 comp 5:00 200                                                                
[2]  16:00 A task2 comp 3:00 100                                                                    
[3]  11:00 B task1 incomp 7:00 100                                                                                
[4]  17:00 B task2 comp 7:00 100                                                      
[5]  15:00 C task1 incomp 5:00 420                                               
[6]  19:00 C task2 comp 6:00 115
```

**So I need to extract lines and put them together which will looks like this:**

```
[1]  10:00 A task1 comp 5:00 100                                                                
[2]  16:00 B task2 comp 3:00 100                                                                    
[3]  11:00 A task1 incomp 7:00 100                                                                                
[4]  17:00 B task2 comp 7:00 100                                                      
[5]  15:00 A task1 incomp 5:00 100                                               
[6]  19:00 B task2 comp 6:00 100
```

I have written a few functions and here's the one that looks most probably to run but still got error.

```
fuc = function(filename = "data.log")
{
  rl = readLines(data)
  spl = strsplit(rl[-1], " ") #split data with spaces
  pattern = grep("A.* 100", spl, value = TRUE) #grep the lines that have group A and credit 100

  if(pattern !=0) #if the pattern grep is different from 0
  {
    pattern2 = grep("B.*100", spl, value = TRUE) #grep lines that have group B and credit 100 that follows pattern above
    if(pattern2 !=0) #if pattern2 is different from 0
      print(pattern) 
  }
```

so this function run okay then I try it with my data

```
fuc("data.log")
```

I got error :

```
Error in if (pattern != 0) { : argument is of length zero
```

I got suggestion from others, since I strsplit the data already, 
I can grep it with something like

```
grep(x[2] == "A" & x[6] == "100", x[2] == "B" & x[6] == "100", spl, value = TRUE)
```

But that's not working.....

Please help me out

Comment: Good work with uploading your code and data but can you also explain what you're trying to do?

Comment: just comment on my code,thanks! I think I miss a command to tell R find lines of group B with credit 100 that is right after group A with credit 100?

Comment: Thanks, I was actually asking about what your end goal is. Can you describe what should be happening in plain words?

Comment: In words, I would like to have a new data frame that only include pairs of lines group A with credit 100 followed by lines of group B with credit 100. Am I explaining clear enough? Please let me know if I should explain it more! Thanks !!

Comment: So I got another suggestion said I should remove elements "0" if there's any in lines before I do anything...(since some lines have the hours "0") . The code to omit "0" should be something like: spl[spl != '0'] ? I don't quite get it ....

Comment: Why `strsplit` the data to then `grep` the individual elements? Just use your `pattern` commands on `rl` not the `strsplit` data. And `if( pattern != 0 )` should *probably* be `if( length( pattern ) == 0L )`

Comment: I do strsplit because someone told me that I need to change as character type....Could you explain a little bit on why it should probably be if(length(pattern) == 0L) ? What does 0L means ? Thanks !!

Comment: If `length( pattern ) == 0L` mean if pattern is a zero length vector (i.e. the first pattern was not found). `0L` means explicitly the integer `0` (`L` after any natural number means treat it as integer not floating point). You could just type `0` but better to be safe. Importantly... does it give you the results you expect?!

Comment: it turns out to be character(0) which is not expected. Still trying to edit on the function.....

Comment: Can you post a sample dataset of 10-15 rows and sample output based on ONLY those 10-15 rows? Your current example does not connect to your plain words explanation.

Comment: Here's the 10-15rows:
    `[10]  08:00 B task2 comp 7:00 100`<br/>
    `[11]  10:00 C task1 incomp 0 420`<br/>
    `[12]  12:00 C task2 comp 6:00 115`<br/>
    `[13]  13:00 A task1 incomp 0 090`<br/>                                                                                                                
    `[14]  16:00 A task2 incomp 6:00 100`<br/>
    `[15]  02:00 B task2 comp 3:00 100`<br/>
 
Sample output would contain only rows that match:
    `[14]  16:00 A task2 incomp 6:00 100`<br/>
    `[15]  02:00 B task2 comp 3:00 100`<br/>

Comment: Sorry, I try my best to make the code in comments wrap (with the tips given on stackflow comment Markdown help) ....but...err...sorry...

Comment: Like SimonO pointed out:  you want to check `length(pattern)` , not the **value** of `pattern`

Comment: But it gives the result of character(0) ....which shouldn't be since there are a lot pair of the rows/lines that match what I want to grep